# Check if current thread is UI/main thread in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we check if the current thread is main thread or background thread in flutter(dart) ?

e.g. In iOS(swift), we can check so by `Thread.isMainThread`.

Comment: There is no thread in Dart. Instead they use aync and await. Check this out for better understanding : [https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: @ChinkySight Like in iOS, we call APIs asynchronously in background thread, then update UI after response in main thread. Calling API on main thread will block UI. I thought dart is also working the same way.

Comment: Dart does not have threads. But, yeah it can run function and processes asynchronously.

Comment: "There is no thread in Dart" is so false. Dart is (almost) singlethreaded, and it can spawn threads with no problems (called isolated)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `Isolate.current.debugName`

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate/debugName.html